# Using OR in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 radio button that does exactly the same command. So I am trying to put them in 1 sub using OR.

The difference between is that 1 radio button is "form controls" and the other is "activeX controls".

I tried with the below code in module, and haven't success.

radion button names
form control: temp_opt_csmin
ActiveX control: opt_csmin

```
Sub opt_csmin_Click()

    If Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("temp_opt_csmin").OLEFormat.Object.Value = "1" Or Worksheets("sheet1").opt_csmin.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M2").Value = "MINIMUM"
    End If

End Sub
```

However, without `Or Worksheets("sheet1").opt_csmin.Value = True` it works.

Is it possible join them using OR?

Thank you very much.

Comment: on click, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me. You need to understand how are you calling the code?

```
'~~> This code is linked with temp_opt_csmin using Assign Macro 
Sub temp_opt_csmin_Click()
    If Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("temp_opt_csmin").OLEFormat.Object.Value = "1" Or _
    Worksheets("sheet1").opt_csmin.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M2").Value = "MINIMUM"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Code is the click event of the ActiveX control
Private Sub opt_csmin_Click()
    If Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("temp_opt_csmin").OLEFormat.Object.Value = "1" Or _
    Worksheets("sheet1").opt_csmin.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M2").Value = "MINIMUM"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: okay, so I need need to write them in 2 different sub. (which is what i have now)

Comment: No. It doesn't make sense writing two subs and check both of them using OR. If you want to use both subs then just check if that particular control is checked :)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I have 2 subs, controlling one each at the moment (without the OR).

Comment: So what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Thanks. It works when i try it with a blank excel, and doesn't when I am doing it with what I have. The code is correct and properly somewhere else has clash due to names or objects.

Comment: kool. feel free to ask questions if you are stuck :)